# Xcode - C++ Code for Terminal program will not run

Tags: c++, xcode

I am currently trying to use Xcode to edit/run C++ code. However, everytime I run it, I will get a

```
Message from debugger: unable to attach
Program ended with exit code: -1
```

error in the terminal. No matter what I run, it will return this error. What does this mean and how can I resolve it?
I have Xcode 10 on MacOS 10.13.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Message from debugger: unable to attach" when running Tests on OSX app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613223/message-from-debugger-unable-to-attach-when-running-tests-on-osx-app)

Answer (score 0):

Does this affect only one particular project or all/ a different project (e.g. basic "hello world" program),too?

Comment: If other projects are affected by this issue, to try reinstalling Xcode